# How do you sum the same products in an invoice?

Tags: sql, transactions, sum

I have this query:

```
declare @usuario as varchar(50), @fecha as datetime
set @usuario ='angel'
set @fecha ='2011/08/07'

select DetalleCompra .id_ali  as [Clave],Alimento .nomAli as [Nombre Alimento], 
    (select sum (cantidad) 
     from DetalleCompra 
     inner join Alimento on DetalleCompra .id_ali =Alimento .id_ali 
     where DetalleCompra .usuario =@usuario  and fecha =@fecha  and FolioCompra is null
    ) as Cantidad, 
    Alimento .precio as [Precio Unitario], ( sum (Cantidad) * precio ) as [Precio Total] 
from DetalleCompra , Alimento 
where DetalleCompra .id_ali =Alimento.id_ali 
    and usuario =@usuario  and  fecha =CONVERT(datetime, @fecha ) and FolioCompra  is null
group by DetalleCompra .id_ali ,Alimento .nomAli , Alimento .precio , DetalleCompra .Cantidad
```

where:

```
usuario=user
fecha=date
detallecompra=details buy
idali= id food
nomali=food's name
foliocompra=folio purchases
precio=price
cantidad=quantity
precio total=total price
```

I want to get a list, but if the products are the same, I want to sum them and get the total price of them.

They have a username and a date, and they are null until the user "accepts" them.

I want to get the list where the `idali` appears twice or more they sum that row, and sum the total price too.

Comment: you know, you could make your question MUCH more understandable for others to answer...

Comment: sorry maybe i dont have a great english

Comment: formatting has nothing to do with english....

Comment: I love this question because it really shows how relative the whole, meaningful variable names, thing is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you are looking for something like this.

The query groups the data by id (`id_ali`), name (`nomAli`) and price (`precio`)  columns. It then sums up the quantity (cantidad) to create the `Total Quantity` column (I just wrote it in English). Also, formulates the `Precio Total` column using the quantity and price columns.

If the column fecha contains only date values without any timestamps, you can do simple equal to comparison instead of using DATEDIFF.

```
DECLARE @usuario AS VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @fecha AS DATETIME

SET @usuario ='angel'
SET @fecha ='2011/08/07'

SELECT      dc.id_ali   AS [Clave]
        ,   al.nomAli   AS [Nombre Alimento]
        ,   al.precio   AS [Precio Unitario]
        ,   SUM(cantidad)   AS [Total Quantity]
        ,   SUM(cantidad) * al. precio as [Precio Total]            
FROM        DetalleCompra   dc
INNER JOIN  Alimento        al
ON          dc.id_ali       = al.id_ali 
WHERE       usuario         = @usuario  
AND         FolioCompra     is null
AND         DATEDIFF(DAY, fecha, @fecha) = 0
GROUP BY    dc.id_ali 
        ,   al.nomAli 
        ,   al.precio
```